# How to get all the specified jars mentioned in the pom.xml and transitively dependent jars?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have only the POM file using which I need to write a script to automatically download all the dependency files and output to custom mentioned path.

I just want to achieve the above using mvn command in command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html):

> `dependency:copy-dependencies` takes the list of project direct dependencies and optionally transitive dependencies and copies them to a specified location, stripping the version if desired. This goal can also be run from the command line.

From the project root, invoking on the command line

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=...
```

will copy all your project direct and transitive dependencies to the specified [output directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory). If those dependencies are not already in your local Maven repository, they will be downloaded from Maven Central (or from a custom repository).

Comment: Is there any way to download the dependencies whose  <optional> tag is set to true? I can't edit the POM files which is available in 2nd level transitively dependant jars.

Comment: @DineshRavi Nope, [optional dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) are meant not to be inherited so Maven will not consider it as a transitive dependency. There's no way around that.