# How to download the souce of jars to custom location in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

This is follow up post of [How to get all the specified jars mentioned in the pom.xml and transitively dependent jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34694214/2018343)
Except that I am looking to download the source of the both dependent and transitively dependent jars to custom mentioned location.

I have tried following command but it didn't works.

```
mvn dependency:sources -DoutputDirectory=.../
```

It didn't worked.

```
mvn dependency:sources dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=.../
```

It didn't worked.

Comment: What kind of custom location? In Maven you usually use repositories for such purposes...and if you really need those artifacts deploy them to a repository manager and use them from there...

Comment: did you try mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=somewhere -Dclassifier=sources as suggested in my answer?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo: Yes. Its working Fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source jar is normally available via Maven using a [classifier](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies), so that for the same Maven coordinates (GAV, groupId, artifactId, version) you can have more than one artefact related to the same build (i.e. default application/library jar, sources jar, test sources jar, javadoc jar, etc.), as also explained in another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909634/what-is-the-purpose-of-classifier-tag-in-maven). The standard classifier for sources is `sources`, created by the [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

The [copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) can be configured to fetch a certain classifier via the `classifier` option.

So in your case, to get the sources of your dependencies to an external folder, you can invoke the command as following:

`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=somewhere -Dclassifier=sources`

Note the additional `-Dclassifier=sources` option.

An example of pom configuration to achieve the same is also explained in the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/using-dependencies-sources.html) of the Dependency Plugin, using the following snippet:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>src-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <!-- use copy-dependencies instead if you don't want to explode the sources -->
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>sources</classifier>
              <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/sources</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Beware though that Maven doesn't know about sources, it only knows about artefacts. So if the sources (classified) artefact is not available via its GAV+C, Maven will find it and as such will not download any source.